# Lost connection to Mysql Server during query i try a lot of solutions but not working

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, mysql-workbench

i had successfully installed python and django and i am trying to migrate djanto to WAMP Mysql server and i had tried a lot of solutions Like increase the maximum allowed packet of Mysql and the connection timeout to 6000 but all of these things doesn't work !!

[image: Here is the image of mysql Settings]

and i have this code in the **init**.py

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: You will most likely get better answers if you [edit] your question to give a more complete explanation of the circumstances. Do you lose the connection when your django instance runs a particular query? When it has a lot of load? Please tell us more.

Comment: When it has a lot of load it still for 30 second loading and then show me this error message

Comment: The problem was in the Port number of Mysql server i wrote it 8080 (The apache port PHP) but it should be 3306